# Как добавить точки к тексту?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как добавить точки к тексту?
длина ведь может быть разной
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Вам очень сильно помогут эти статьи из документации:

- [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)
- [padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

Если в кратце, они могут дополнять в начале или в конце строку символами до заданной длины

Comment: а без js нельзя?

Comment: Если без JS, вам поможет эта [статья](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html)

Comment: @oksanaТкачик а зачем тогда отмечать в метках js?

Comment: @EzioMercer не знал о таких функциях, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @ΝNL993 отметка скорее всего была поставлена как один из способов решения задачи. Ведь могло оказаться, что кроме как JS эту задачу не решить))) А на счёт новых функий всегда полезно смотреть за обновлениями в JS время от времени, очень много полезного бывает))